# tensorflow_core._api.v2.random has no attribute Generator

Tags: tensorflow

I am seeing the following error when I try to import `tensorflow_addons` with tensorflow 2.1

```
> import tensorflow_addons as tfa
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core._api.v2.random' has no attribute 'Generator'
```

Comment: Had the same problem, I saw a warning saying that tensorflow_addons does not support tensorflow versions lower than 2.2. I upgraded and the error stopped appearing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an incompability between your Tensorflow and Tensorflow-addons versions.
To solve your problem, uninstall your current version and replace it with the right one which you can get by checking this [table](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons#python-op-compatibility-matrix)

A little reminder:
To check your Tensorflow version type in terminal:

```
python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by patching `tf.random.Generator`

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.Generator = None  # Patch for a bug
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your tensorflow version -

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

Check the corresponding tf-addons version [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons#python-op-compatibility-matrix)

Uninstall the previous version and install the correct one -

```
pip uninstall tensorflow-addons
pip install tensorflow-addons==[version-number]
```

Eg - `pip install tensorflow-addons==0.9.1`  for tensorflow version 2.1.0